# Why does $ O = |\phi\rangle \langle\psi|$ equal $O =\lambda |\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ for the 2 vectors of Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-states

If we take the operator $$\hat{O} = |\phi\rangle \langle\psi| \space \space(1)$$ whereby $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ are two vectors of the hilbert space.

My notes also state that $\hat{O}$ can be written as
$$\hat{O} = \lambda P{\phi}P_{\psi} \space \space (2)$$ where $\lambda$ is a constant.

$P{\phi}$ and $P_{\psi}$ are projector operators associated with $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$.

My question is how can this be.

Surely if I write it in terms of state I see the following:

$$ \hat{O} = \lambda |\phi\rangle \langle\phi|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$$

I do not see how (1) and (2) equal one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be possible if $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle\neq0$, and $\lambda$ would be $$\lambda=\frac{1}{\langle\phi|\psi\rangle}$$